# Prove that if P and Q are permutation matrices with $(P-I)(Q−I) = 0$ then they represent disjoint permutations.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations

Before even starting let me make clear this question is not duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745261/prove-or-disprove-that-pq-p-q-i-if-p-and-q-are-disjoint-permutation) which asks for proving just the inverse statement.

> Prove that if $P$ and $Q$ are permutation matrices with $(P-I)(Q−I)=0$ then, they represent disjoint permutations

**MY TRY :-** Let P and Q be the matrices corresponding to the respective permutations $p$ and $q$ in cycle notation. Let $p$ and $q$ do not represent disjoint permutations. For e.g. $p = (123)$ and $q=(345)$ We have that $$
P =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Now $PQ$ being a permutation will not have two $1$'s in same row. But $P+Q-I$ have two $1$'s and one $-1$ in the "third" row, and $PQ\neq P+Q-I$ which is equivalent $(P-I)(Q-I)\neq 0$ so we reach a contradiction visually. But isn't there some clear method to prove it theoritically?

I am new to group theory. Please ask for clarifications in case of any discrepancies.

Comment: use $(P-I)(Q-I)=0$

Comment: @Spartan He means that $PQ=P+Q-I$ is equivalent to $(P-I)(Q-I)=0$.

Comment: There are plenty examples of matrices $A$ and $B$ that are nonzero yet $AB=0$. Such matrices give raise to $P=A+I$ and $Q=B+I$.

Comment: @Scientifica But P and Q need to be permutation matrices.

Comment: My advice is to forget about the precise $PQ$.  Instead, just note $P+Q-I$ is a matrix with only $0,1$ as entries.  Then the diagonal of $P+Q$ has $1,2$ as entries.  Then ...

Comment: To show they are disjoint, we show either the $k$th diagonal entry of $P$ is $1$ or the $k$th diagonal entry of $Q$ is $1$ (or both), for all $k$.  The equation then doesn't matter, and all we need is that $P+Q-I$ is a matrix with only $0$s and $1$s on the diagonal.

Comment: You've essentially proved it.  Just try to generalize the argument you made.  Under what conditions does a row of $P+Q-I$ have one $1$ and the remaining elements $0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\pi$ denote the permutation corresponding to $P$, and let $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb F^n$. Suppose that $\pi = \sigma_1\cdots \sigma_k$ is a decomposition into disjoint cycles (including all "cycles with length $1$"). Let $S_k = \{a_1,\dots,a_\ell\}$, where $\sigma_k = (a_1 \cdots a_\ell)$.

Note that $\ker(P - I)$ is spanned by the vectors $v_k = \sum_{j \in S_k} e_j$. In particular, if $S_k = e_p$, then $e_p \in \ker (P-I)$.  Because $P$ is orthogonal, we have $\operatorname{im}(P - I) = \ker(P - I)^\perp$.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that $PQ = P + Q - I$ is [a priori] stronger than we need.  We may instead simply work with the assumption that the diagonal of $P+Q-I$ only has entries in $\{0,1\}$.

If we let $1 \leq k \leq n$ be arbitrary and write $A_{kk}$ for the $k$th diagonal entry of $A$, then $$\begin{align*}(P+Q)_{kk}-1 = (P&+Q-I)_{kk} \in \{0,1\} \\ &\iff (P+Q)_{kk} \in \{1,2\} \\ &\iff P_{kk} = 1 \text{ or } Q_{kk} = 1\end{align*}$$
where the justification for the last $\implies$ is due to $P_{kk}, Q_{kk} \in \{0,1\}.$

Now we're basically finished.  That the permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ represent disjoint permutations is equivalent to the statement that, for any $1\leq k\leq n,$ $$P_{kk} = 0 \implies Q_{kk} = 1 \\\text{ and } \\Q_{kk} = 0 \implies P_{kk} = 1,$$ which is logically equivalent, since $P_{kk}, Q_{kk} \in \{0,1\}$, to $$P_{kk} = 1 \text{ or } Q_{kk} = 1$$

---

A final note: If $P,Q$ are permutation matrices and the diagonal of $P+Q-I$ has entries in $\{0,1\}$, then we can show $PQ = QP = P+Q-I,$ so this is not actually a strengthening/weakening of the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

"$P$ and $Q$ are disjoint" means that for every $i$,
$$
Pe_i \ne e_i \implies Qe_i = e_i\\
Qe_i \ne e_i \implies Pe_i = e_i
$$
but
$$
Qe_i = e_j \ne e_i \implies 0 = (P-I)(Q-I)e_i=(P-I)(e_j-e_i) \\
\implies P(e_j-e_i) = e_j-e_i\implies Pe_i = e_i
$$
and
$$
Pe_i = e_j \ne e_i \implies 0 = (P-I)(Q-I)Q^Te_i=(P-I)(e_i -Q^Te_i) \\
\implies P(e_i-Q^Te_i) = e_j - PQ^Te_i = e_i-Q^Te_i\implies e_i = Q^Te_i\\
\implies Qe_i = e_i
$$

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why the last consequence is obvious? I mean why $P(e_j-e_i) = e_j- e_i$ implies $Pe_i=e_i$ ?

Comment: @LRDPRDX Maybe Exodd has another way, but here's how I saw it: Since $P$ is a permutation matrix, $Pe_j=e_a$ and $Pe_i=e_b$, and then $e_a-e_b=e_j-e_i$ implies $b=i$ by independence.

Comment: Yes, @LRDPRDX, as Brian said. Or, in a more visual way, $P$ is a permutation, and $e_j-e_i$ is a vector with one $1$ and one $-1$, so $P$ just maps these two entries in other positions.

Comment: What happens when P=Q=I? This case is missing!!

Comment: @LawrenceMano It is not missing... Simply the statement is true because you cannot find $i$ such that $Pe_i\ne e_i$ or $Qe_i\ne e_i$

Comment: If P=I and Q=I then the hypothesis is satisfied but conclusion is not true since I and I are not disjoint permutations!

Comment: @LawrenceMano $I$ and $I$ are disjoint permutations...

Comment: @LawrenceMano https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Disjoint_Permutations

Comment: @Exodd Thank you. Thank you very much for making me realize the correct definition of disjoint permutations. The support of I is empty and hence I and I are disjoint permutations. Am I correct?

Comment: @LawrenceMano yes, that's a way to say it